# Get occurrences of text in cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

Is there a way to get the number of occurrences of a certain text in an unordered list without using any Javascript in `Cypress`?

I have something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        14 May, 2018
    </li>

    <li>
        14 May, 2018
    </li>

    <li>
        23 Aug, 2018
    </li>

    <li>
        14 May, 2018
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to count the occurrences of `14 May, 2018`. I can not use `contain()` as it would only get the first element.

I did not find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was rather too easy.

```
cy.get(`ul`)
   .get('li:contains(14 May, 2018)')
   .should('have.length', 3);
```

Comment: It would be good to add a link to [the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Length)

Comment: This `.get('li:contains(14 May, 2018)')` this looks like a `.contains('li', '14 May, 2018')` in disguise.

Comment: Not really: CypressError: `cy.contains()` cannot be passed a `length` option because it will only ever return 1 element. You have to use what @aitchkhan suggested